# Find A Cell's ID of input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this jQuery plugin (https://github.com/imgss/table) that turns a table into an editable grid, and I am stuck trying to pass the table cell's ID *(so I can perform an ajax update when the cell loses focus)* to the dynamically create input/select field.

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9x0egwf7/

On line 75 I'm trying to assign the `<td>` elements ID to the input's ID property:

```js
input.id = input.closest('td').prop("id");
```

Which I would then be able to retrieve from lines 86 and 95:

```js
var idValue = input.prop("id");
```

I'm having trouble assigning the cell's ID to the dynamically created input field - can anyone please help?

Thank you!

Comment: ID's must be unique. Unless you're going to remove the ID from the `td`, it wouldn't be correct to do this.

Comment: If you're going to use jsFiddle, why not put the JS in the pane that expects JS?

Comment: Are you really want to use jQuery version 1.12.0? There are much newer one.

Comment: If the activeChange event data provided proper row and column it is easy to get the cell id using those index. The data in that event doesn't seem to put out correct row value. Did you change the output code for it?

Comment: I've updated the JSFiddle and Jquery version

Comment: @charlietfl - it looks like I might have modified the code the wrong way - you're right b/c the row/col values are wrong. If I roll it back - how would I use that to get the TD's ID?

Comment: Put the headers in a `<thead>` instead of in the `<tbody>`. Then use `$('tbody tr').eq(data.row).children().eq(data.col).attr('id')`. If data to create table comes in from api as array would be easy to get it from array also

Comment: I am making assumptions how the row value is generated...not sure if it counts the header row as zero or ignores it...didn't get into code too deep. If you do a reversion version with the original plugin only and it produces proper values in the change event will be glad to help there getting the proper id

Comment: I've updated the JSFiddle link - it seems the library only correctly outputs the row number when it's based on DIVs and not a table.

Comment: Their demo uses table element.

Comment: @charlietfl - thank you, I believe your comment to put it in a tbody is going to work - thank you!